# Laravel 4: Adding an extra key/value pair to array (object) retrieved from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I wonder if someone can help me, as I am beginning to get frustrated here... I have a database table containing info relating to images. One column is 'filename'. After having retrieved the array of images, I want to add an extra key to the array called 'filepath' which will be in the format `'/path/to/images' . array[$i]['filename']`

Simple enough right? But I can't seem to do it (without using some ridiculously verbose code). Here is what I have:

```
    $array = DB::table('tour_images')->where('tour_id','=',$tourID)->get();
    $images = $array;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $img){
        $images[$i]['filepath'] = '/upload/tour_images/' . $img['file_name'];
        $i++;
    }
```

But I get '*Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*' I guess it's because the first line of code is returning an *object* rather than an *array*, right? So I try to use:

```
$array = DB::table('tour_images')->where('tour_id','=',$tourID)->get()->toArray();
```

Guess what, it doesn't work. OK, somebody help me now, please...

EDIT: Error returned from above: '*Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object*'

Comment: You need to call `get()` before `toArray()`. `->get()->toArray()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter I tried that- please see edit. Thanks.

Comment: why did you mix foreach and $i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would just work with the objects. Like that:

```
$images = DB::table('tour_images')->where('tour_id','=',$tourID)->get();
foreach($images as $i => $img){
    $images[$i]->src = '/upload/tour_images/' . $img->file_name;
}
```

You can also convert it into an array. `toArray()` doesn't work because it's an array of plain objects but casting it as array should convert it. Anyways you have to do it for every row in the resultset.

```
$results = DB::table('tour_images')->where('tour_id','=',$tourID)->get();
$images = array();
foreach($results as $result){
    $img = (array) $result;
    $img['filepath'] = '/upload/tour_images/' . $img['file_name'];
    $images[] = $img;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @lukasgeiter, your first solution works perfectly. OK, I need to remember to try and work with objects when using Laravel I think... otherwise I am trying to fight the system rather than working with it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `$images` is a array, but `$img` is a stdClass

So you should use `->` to reference it's property

like below:

```
$images = DB::table('tour_images')->where('tour_id','=',$tourID)->get();

foreach($images as $img) {
    $img->filepath = '/upload/tour_images/' . $img->file_name;
}
```